# Google Sheets Script - Loading a File from a Drive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a spreadsheet that is a template. I have a submit button that saves the data in a file (by date and customer name) into a Google Drive Folder.

I want to edit an already submitted template, so I created a dropdown menu that pulls the file name from the folder using this code:

```
function onOpen() {
list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders() }


function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B8xnkPYxGFbUMktOWm14TVA3Yjg'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name']); //,'ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName()) //,file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(2,2,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}

function onEdit(e) {


  openFile() }



function openFile(e) {
  var sheet = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet with the dropdown list.
  var range = "A1"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.
  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sheet && e.range.getA1Notation() == range) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(e.value);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var f = file.next();
      var url = f.getUrl();
      var script = "<script>window.open('" + url + "', '_blank').focus();google.script.host.close()</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Open ' + f.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

I then created a Dropdown of a list of these files by name.
I want to create an OnEdit Script that can open a file (by selecting from the Dropdown menu the name of the file).

Any pointers on how to pursue this?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about it? You have already had the dropdown list. When you select one of filename from the dropdown list, you want to open the file as a new tab of the browser. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike , You got it for the most part. I'd prefer it to open it in the same tab (to replace the template).  But if that is not possible, a new tab is my second best choice.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated my original post to include your code (and the entire code). However the Dropdown does nothing and it does not work. Sheet name = Sheet1 and Dropdown is on Cell A1.

Comment: I just found this in the StackDriver logs: Jan 20, 2019, 12:45:52 AM
ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. at openFile(Code:30) at onEdit(Code:23). Does that help?

Comment: Wonderful! It worked! Thankyou!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have already had the dropdown list.
- When you select one of filename from the dropdown list, you want to open the file as a new tab of the browser.

I understood about your question like above. How about this sample script? The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Select a filename at the dropdown list.
2. When the filename is existing, open a dialog for running Javascript and the selected file is opened to the new tab of the browser.
3. When the new tab is opened, the focus is moved to the new tab.
4. After the new tab was opened, the dialog of Spreadsheet is closed.

#### Sample script:

When you use this sample script, please do the following flow.

1. Please copy and paste the following sample script to the bound script of the Spreadsheet which has the dropdown list.
2. This script uses OnEdit event. So please install OnEdit trigger to `openFile()`.
3. Please modify `Sheet1` of `var sheet = "Sheet1"`. This sample supposes that the dropdown list is put in "Sheet1".
4. Please modify `A1` of `var range = "A1"`. This sample supposes that the dropdown list is put in a cell "A1".

Script:

```
function openFile(e) {
  var sheet = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet with the dropdown list.
  var range = "A1"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.
  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sheet && e.range.getA1Notation() == range) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(e.value);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var f = file.next();
      var url = f.getUrl();
      var script = "<script>window.open('" + url + "', '_blank').focus();google.script.host.close()</script>";
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(script);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Open ' + f.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- After you set above, when you select one of filenames at the dropdown list, the file is opened as new tab.
- This script is a simple sample. So please modify it for your situation.
- In this sample script, when there are several files with the same filename, the first searched file is opened. If you want to modify it, please modify the script for your situation.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

### Edit:

The reason of the issue is `function onEdit(e) {openFile()}`. `e` of `onEdit(e)` is not given to `openFile()`. By this, such error occurs. So please install the OnEdit trigger to the function `openFile()`. So please do as follows.

1. Remove the function of `onEdit()`.
2. Install `openFile()` as the OnEdit trigger.

   - By this, when you select the filename at the dropdown list, `openFile()` is automatically run by the installed trigger. At that time, e of the event object is given.

#### How to install OnEdit trigger:

1. Open the script editor.
2. Edit -> Current project's triggers.
3. Click "Add Trigger".
4. Set "openFile" for "Choose which function to run".
5. Set "From spreadsheet" for "Select event source".
6. Set "On edit" for "Select event type".

Comment: @Ben I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If the script didn't work even when you modify above, can you share the spreadsheet? I would like to confirm your situation, because in my environment, I confirmed that the script works fine. When you share the spreadsheet, of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Ben I think that it is new situation. So can you post it as new question? Because adding new situation to the existing question might confuse other users. And I cannot understand about your current situation from your comment. So when you post it as new question, can you add the detail information? The information will help users think of your solution. If this was not what you want, I apologize.